# How to filter pandas dataframe based on range of values in column?

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, numpy, arraylist

I have a column in my dataset counting the number of consecutive events. This counter resets to 0 if there is no event for X amount of time. I am only interested in occurrences where there are 3 or less events. How would I filter for these in my dataframe?

```
# sample dataset
event_counter = [0,1,2,3,4,0,1,2,3,4,5,6,0,1,2]
time = [1,2,3,4,5,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,19,20,21]
pd.DataFrame({"Time of Event" : time, "Event Counter" : event_counter})
```

the expected output should only include the rows where time == 19,20,or 21 as the event counter starting at time 19 only has 3 consecutive events

Answer (score 3):

Use [`diff`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.diff.html) and [`cumsum`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.cumsum.html) to group the successive events. Then [`groupyby.cumcount`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.cumcount.html) and [boolean indexing](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) to filter the groups:

```
group = (~df['Event Counter'].diff().ge(1)).cumsum()
m = df.groupby(group)['Event Counter'].transform('size').le(3)

out = df[m]
```

output:

```
    Time of Event  Event Counter
12             19              0
13             20              1
14             21              2
```

Intermediates:

```
    Time of Event  Event Counter  diff  ~(diff>=1)  group  size      m
0               1              0   NaN        True      1     5  False
1               2              1   1.0       False      1     5  False
2               3              2   1.0       False      1     5  False
3               4              3   1.0       False      1     5  False
4               5              4   1.0       False      1     5  False
5               9              0  -4.0        True      2     7  False
6              10              1   1.0       False      2     7  False
7              11              2   1.0       False      2     7  False
8              12              3   1.0       False      2     7  False
9              13              4   1.0       False      2     7  False
10             14              5   1.0       False      2     7  False
11             15              6   1.0       False      2     7  False
12             19              0  -6.0        True      3     3   True
13             20              1   1.0       False      3     3   True
14             21              2   1.0       False      3     3   True
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use the built in [.isin()](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.isin.html) function of pandas.

Your code would look something like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"Time of Event" : time, "Event Counter" : event_counter})

# Use the isin() function to filter based on a list
df[df["Time of Event"].isin([19,20,21])]
```

Output:

```
Time of Event  Event Counter
12             19              0
13             20              1
14             21              2
```